# Please let me know how to get/read the content of type std:string array in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

Please let me know how to get the content of csNameBuffer array of type std:string in WinDBG
I have tried using the command :

```
dt -r objNames csNameBuffer[0] _Bx _Buf
```

Output is :

```
Local var @ 0x2cf7f4 Type CBase<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >
   +0x000 csNameBuffer    : 0x005a981c std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

---

[Cross-post on MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/perfmon/thread/88b47c75-9eb1-455d-844f-c4443efce3a2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !STL commands to look at STL objects in windbg. You can usually get the direct pointer to the underlying string as well if you look through the structure, but I've noticed that in the past that depending upon if I was in debug or release mode it made significant changes to how the STL objects were actually stored.